# Removing zombie process from the process table

Tags: process, process-management, exit, architecture, zombie-process

Can somebody please explain when parent process receives the exit status of a dead child process via `wait`, who actually reallocates the memory of the child process and removes it from the process table?

Answer (score 4):

The kernel assumes that the parent process is interested in knowing the result of any child process that it forked. When a child process terminates, it automatically sends a `SIGCHLD` signal to the parent process.  If the parent is explicitly ignoring the `SIGCHLD` signal, the child is immediately cleaned up and removed completely (and does not become a zombie). Otherwise, the child becomes a zombie until the parent calls one of the `wait` functions to retrieve termination status from the child.

If the status is not retrieved, child remains a zombie. However if the parent process exits before the child process, the child is adopted by `init` (process 1), which collects the status immediately, effectively removing the zombie process.

Comment: thank You, but what if the parent process doesn't exist before the child process, and father received status value, who will remove ZOMBIE? also init?

Comment: @macindows: Yes. If the parent process doesn't exist, responsibility passes to its parent, then that process's parent, and so on. If no other ancestor process currently exists, it will end up with `init`.

Answer (score 4):

Manipulating the process table and the memory mappings is always the kernel's job. The kernel acts when some process makes a system call. When a process exits, all of the resources that it uses, including memory, except for the entry in the process table, are deleted − that's what the `_exit` system call does. Then, when the parent process calls `wait` or `waitpid`, part of that system call's job is to clean up the process table entry. The parent process may decide to call `wait` whenever it wants (if the parent is `init`, it calls `wait` pretty much all the time).